# Same dockerfile (2 lines), but doesn't build properly on a particular build of Ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu

A little torn here as I spun up a newer version of Ubuntu only to find out my Dockerfile doesn't build properly. Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:3.1.4-buster
RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y
```

That's literally it. On my Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS server, this works flawlessly. On my new Ubuntu 22.04 server, this fails with the following error:

```
...
#0 9.504 Unpacking libx11-6:amd64 (2:1.6.7-1+deb10u3) over (2:1.6.7-1+deb10u2) ...
#0 9.646 Setting up libpython3.7-minimal:amd64 (3.7.3-2+deb10u5) ...
#0 9.665 Setting up libx11-data (2:1.6.7-1+deb10u3) ...
#0 9.682 Setting up python3.7-minimal (3.7.3-2+deb10u5) ...
#0 9.804 Traceback (most recent call last):
#0 9.804   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/py_compile.py", line 212, in <module>
#0 9.804     sys.exit(main())
#0 9.804   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/py_compile.py", line 204, in main
#0 9.804     compile(filename, doraise=True)
#0 9.804   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/py_compile.py", line 169, in compile
#0 9.804     importlib._bootstrap_external._write_atomic(cfile, bytecode, mode)
#0 9.804   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 112, in _write_atomic
#0 9.804 PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python3.7/__pycache__/__future__.cpython-37.pyc.140673411499376'
#0 9.809 dpkg: error processing package python3.7-minimal (--configure):
#0 9.809  installed python3.7-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
#0 9.809 Setting up libx11-6:amd64 (2:1.6.7-1+deb10u3) ...
#0 9.827 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3.7:
#0 9.827  python3.7 depends on python3.7-minimal (= 3.7.3-2+deb10u5); however:
#0 9.827   Package python3.7-minimal is not configured yet.
#0 9.827
#0 9.827 dpkg: error processing package python3.7 (--configure):
#0 9.827  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
#0 9.827 Setting up libpython3.7-stdlib:amd64 (3.7.3-2+deb10u5) ...
#0 9.841 Setting up libx11-dev:amd64 (2:1.6.7-1+deb10u3) ...
#0 9.853 Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.28-10+deb10u2) ...
#0 9.892 Processing triggers for mime-support (3.62) ...
#0 9.927 Errors were encountered while processing:
#0 9.927  python3.7-minimal
#0 9.927  python3.7
#0 9.939 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

On the Ubuntu 22.04 server, my docker version is 20.10.24 build 297e128, and on my Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS server, it's version 20.10.12 build e91ed57.

To my knowledge, a Dockerfile is supposed to build the exact same way, so I'm a little torn as to why that's not the case even though they're both pulling from the same source.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.